# How to transfer a file from source server to destination server and delete/move the file from source server

Tags: file, shell, unix, ftp, transfer

I need to transfer files from one server to another server. In source there will be continuous incoming files. So, when ever I transfer these file to my destination server , I don't need them in the same directory. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `rsync` with the `--remove-source-files` flag:

```
rsync -avz --remove-source-files /my/source/file.txt user@remotehost:/my/target/dir
```

Comment: If i want to move the source file to different directory after transfer. Is it possible?